# how to unit test data class property with high oder function in Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

How can I uni test data class which having a high-order function parametere

```
class PersonViewModel {
    fun testPersonContent() = Person(name = "ABC", cta = {})
}

data class Person(val name: String, val cta: () -> Unit)


import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Test

class PersonViewModelTest {

    @Test
    fun `Test content same`() {
        val model = PersonViewModel()
        val actual = model.testPersonContent()
        val expected = Person(name = "ABC", cta = {}
        )
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is surely a simplified example, which also makes it hard to suggest something useful, except "don't"? Depending where your function comes from, it's reference is the same and therefore comparable (e.g. by using something like `val defaultCta : () -> Unit = {}`). Comparing that two functions do the same is only achievable if you test those functions instead...but maybe I missed the point...

Comment: this is the data object passed to UI, so I just want to check the correct CTA action function pass to the UI,